# Heroku deploy Code loops forever till time out

Tags: reactjs, heroku

trying to deploy react website.

works on GitHub, deploys on personal.

loops this code until it times out on server.

Tried several things to fix it, but rather new to heroku. Can anyone help out a new dev?

Trying to deploy site that uses mongo hosting after this but cant figure out this issue.

site has several pages in react they all work fine.

Site does calls to Facebook, Instagram, and twitter and they all work no issues.

basically everything works except deployment.

```
**-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  10.15.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.11.3

       Resolving node version 10.15.3...
       Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.11.3 (replacing 6.4.1)...
       npm 6.11.3 installed
       Resolving yarn version 1.17.3...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.17.3)...
       Installed yarn 1.17.3

-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > node-sass@4.13.1 install /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/install.js

       Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.1/linux-x64-64_binding.node
       Download complete
       Binary saved to /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
       Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.y9Gan/node-sass/4.13.1/linux-x64-64_binding.node

       > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


       > core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


       > core-js-pure@3.6.4 postinstall /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/node_modules/core-js-pure
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


       > node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/build.js

       Binary found at /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
       Testing binary
       Binary is fine

       > nodemon@2.0.2 postinstall /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0

       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate


       > backend@1.0.0 install /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288
       > cd client && npm install

       added 208 packages from 348 contributors and audited 1494 packages in 10.996s
       found 0 vulnerabilities

       added 1901 packages from 829 contributors and audited 914582 packages in 59.722s
       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build
       Running build

       > backend@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288
       > cd client && npm run build


       > atl-website@1.1.0 build /tmp/build_cd9fcefdac176fb187e7cf1f59c64288/client
       > react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Compiled with warnings.

       ./src/utils/API.js
         Line 2:10:  'func' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

       ./src/components/Layout/Sidebar.js
         Line 7:3:   'MdBorderAll' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
         Line 19:3:  'FaTwitter' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars

       Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
       To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

       File sizes after gzip:

         77.65 KB  build/static/js/3.09e16e2e.chunk.js
         26.68 KB  build/static/css/main.d5d3bbe0.chunk.css
         20.28 KB  build/static/js/4.db1c8c2a.chunk.js
         6.38 KB   build/static/js/0.5213ded1.chunk.js
         4.49 KB   build/static/js/main.0f3b7751.chunk.js
         3.72 KB   build/static/js/6.a609dcc4.chunk.js
         2.73 KB   build/static/css/5.b90ce945.chunk.css
         2.73 KB   build/static/css/7.b90ce945.chunk.css
         2.6 KB    build/static/js/5.c45b14eb.chunk.js
         2.54 KB   build/static/js/7.f5c95ed2.chunk.js
         1.88 KB   build/static/js/9.28000b0c.chunk.js
         1.75 KB   build/static/js/8.cd521c20.chunk.js
         1.67 KB   build/static/js/runtime-main.f9cf8873.js
         1.22 KB   build/static/js/10.056b824f.chunk.js
         224 B     build/static/js/14.7c35130c.chunk.js
         224 B     build/static/js/12.2041d5d7.chunk.js
         222 B     build/static/js/15.93f1aa85.chunk.js
         216 B     build/static/js/13.e5886685.chunk.js
         141 B     build/static/js/11.2369fc97.chunk.js

       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /ATL-RENEGADES-WEBSITE/.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       To publish it at https://joswald123.github.io/ATL-RENEGADES-WEBSITE/ , run:

         npm install --save-dev gh-pages

       Add the following script in your package.json.

           // ...
           "scripts": {
             // ...
             "predeploy": "npm run build",
             "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
           }

       Then run:

         npm run deploy

       Find out more about deployment here:

         bit.ly/CRA-deploy**
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the environmental variables for MLab, or Atlas, or however Database you're supporting in heroku as well. Perhaps  by taking a look at your server file we could guide you through

Comment: const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();


// settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);

//middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

//routes
app.use('/api/events', require('./routes/events'))
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'))
app.use('/api/match', require('./routes/match'))



module.exports = app;

Comment: // Database file

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI 
? process.env.MONGODB_URI 
: 'mongodb://localhost/databasetest';

mongoose.connect(URI, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
})
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('This is a mongoose error' + err)
})

connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('DB is connected');
})

Comment: require('dotenv').config();


const app = require('./src/app');
require('./src/database');

async function main (){
    await app.listen(app.get('port'));
    console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'));
}

main();

Comment: @Juli On Heroku, go to your project, then Settings, then Reveal Config Vars. You'll see two fields. On the key value field, enter: MONGODB_URI      . Now go to your .env file and copy the value after the = sign. (E.I.    MONGODB_URI=YoUrKeY). Then go back to Heroku and paste that key onto the value field. Then click on the more tab on top and select: restart all dynos. Give that a try and see if it works. Good luck